# Unnecessary space between cta banner and hero section

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, frontend

I am facing an issue in HTML and CSS while making a clone of Razorpay and I am having trouble in the cta banner and hero sections, it is showing unnecessary space of about 20px (horizontal bar).

```css
.notbat-wrapper {
  margin: 0%;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.not-clr-wrapper1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 40px;
  background: rgb(43, 131, 234);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.not-clr-wrapper2 {
  /* height: 60px; */
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: -90px;
  background: rgb(231, 241, 253);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 82% 0px, 100% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.not-clr-wrapper3 {
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -42px;
  background: rgb(243, 248, 254);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 82% 0px, 100% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.not-clr-wrapper4 {
  width: 240px;
  margin-right: -42px;
  background: rgb(243, 248, 254);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 82% 0px, 100% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.not-clr-wrapper5 {
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: -42px;
  background: rgb(231, 241, 253);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 82% 0px, 100% 100%, 18% 100%);
}

.not-clr-wrapper6 {
  width: 40px;
  background: rgb(43, 131, 234);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 100% 100%, 100% 0px);
  z-index: 999;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-but {
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #02042A;
  padding: 0px 32px;
  height: 90.96px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.razor-wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #02042A;
  padding: 28px 22px 28px 0px;
}

.razor-img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 1rem;
  fill: #fff;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.razor-wrapper-optns {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pay:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-block-width: 4px;
}

.bank {
  background-color: #02042A;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.bank:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-block-width: 4px;
}

.line:hover {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

.end-wrap {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.flag {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.login-wrapper {
  /* justify-content: center; */
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  background-color: #02042A;
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.sign-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 110px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
}


/* hero section */

.col {
  padding-top: 0%;
  background-color: #02042A;
  height: 558px;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-head {
  margin-left: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tarkeeb.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- -------------------------notification------------------------- -->
  <div class="notbat-wrapper">
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper1"></div>
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper2"></div>
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper3"></div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-text">
        <p>Simplify payroll with RazorpayX Payroll -Fast & Compliant</p>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-but">
        <button>
                    Claim 1 month FREE
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper4"></div>
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper5"></div>
    <div class="not-clr-wrapper6"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- -------------------------header-------------------------- -->


  <div class="header">
    <div class="razor-wrapper">
      <div class="razor-img">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1896 401" focusable="false" class="chakra-icon css-1xy62lf" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="#3395FF" d="M122.63 105.7l-15.75 57.97 90.15-58.3-58.96 219.98 59.88.05L285.05.48"></path><path d="M25.6 232.92L.8 325.4h122.73l50.22-188.13L25.6 232.92m426.32-81.42c-3 11.15-8.78 19.34-17.4 24.57-8.6 5.22-20.67 7.84-36.25 7.84h-49.5l17.38-64.8h49.5c15.56 0 26.25 2.6 32.05 7.9 5.8 5.3 7.2 13.4 4.22 24.6m51.25-1.4c6.3-23.4 3.7-41.4-7.82-54-11.5-12.5-31.68-18.8-60.48-18.8H324.4l-66.5 248.1h53.67l26.8-100h35.2c7.9 0 14.12 1.3 18.66 3.8 4.55 2.6 7.22 7.1 8.04 13.6l9.58 82.6h57.5l-9.32-77c-1.9-17.2-9.77-27.3-23.6-30.3 17.63-5.1 32.4-13.6 44.3-25.4a92.6 92.6 0 0 0 24.44-42.5m130.46 86.4c-4.5 16.8-11.4 29.5-20.73 38.4-9.34 8.9-20.5 13.3-33.52 13.3-13.26 0-22.25-4.3-27-13-4.76-8.7-4.92-21.3-.5-37.8 4.42-16.5 11.47-29.4 21.17-38.7 9.7-9.3 21.04-13.95 34.06-13.95 13 0 21.9 4.5 26.4 13.43 4.6 8.97 4.7 21.8.2 38.5zm23.52-87.8l-6.72 25.1c-2.9-9-8.53-16.2-16.85-21.6-8.34-5.3-18.66-8-30.97-8-15.1 0-29.6 3.9-43.5 11.7-13.9 7.8-26.1 18.8-36.5 33-10.4 14.2-18 30.3-22.9 48.4-4.8 18.2-5.8 34.1-2.9 47.9 3 13.9 9.3 24.5 19 31.9 9.8 7.5 22.3 11.2 37.6 11.2a82.4 82.4 0 0 0 35.2-7.7 82.11 82.11 0 0 0 28.4-21.2l-7 26.16h51.9L709.3 149h-52zm238.65 0H744.87l-10.55 39.4h87.82l-116.1 100.3-9.92 37h155.8l10.55-39.4h-94.1l117.88-101.8m142.4 52c-4.67 17.4-11.6 30.48-20.75 39-9.15 8.6-20.23 12.9-33.24 12.9-27.2 0-36.14-17.3-26.86-51.9 4.6-17.2 11.56-30.13 20.86-38.84 9.3-8.74 20.57-13.1 33.82-13.1 13 0 21.78 4.33 26.3 13.05 4.52 8.7 4.48 21.67-.13 38.87m30.38-80.83c-11.95-7.44-27.2-11.16-45.8-11.16-18.83 0-36.26 3.7-52.3 11.1a113.09 113.09 0 0 0-41 32.06c-11.3 13.9-19.43 30.2-24.42 48.8-4.9 18.53-5.5 34.8-1.7 48.73 3.8 13.9 11.8 24.6 23.8 32 12.1 7.46 27.5 11.17 46.4 11.17 18.6 0 35.9-3.74 51.8-11.18 15.9-7.48 29.5-18.1 40.8-32.1 11.3-13.94 19.4-30.2 24.4-48.8 5-18.6 5.6-34.84 1.8-48.8-3.8-13.9-11.7-24.6-23.6-32.05m185.1 40.8l13.3-48.1c-4.5-2.3-10.4-3.5-17.8-3.5-11.9 0-23.3 2.94-34.3 8.9-9.46 5.06-17.5 12.2-24.3 21.14l6.9-25.9-15.07.06h-37l-47.7 176.7h52.63l24.75-92.37c3.6-13.43 10.08-24 19.43-31.5 9.3-7.53 20.9-11.3 34.9-11.3 8.6 0 16.6 1.97 24.2 5.9m146.5 41.1c-4.5 16.5-11.3 29.1-20.6 37.8-9.3 8.74-20.5 13.1-33.5 13.1s-21.9-4.4-26.6-13.2c-4.8-8.85-4.9-21.6-.4-38.36 4.5-16.75 11.4-29.6 20.9-38.5 9.5-8.97 20.7-13.45 33.7-13.45 12.8 0 21.4 4.6 26 13.9 4.6 9.3 4.7 22.2.28 38.7m36.8-81.4c-9.75-7.8-22.2-11.7-37.3-11.7-13.23 0-25.84 3-37.8 9.06-11.95 6.05-21.65 14.3-29.1 24.74l.18-1.2 8.83-28.1h-51.4l-13.1 48.9-.4 1.7-54 201.44h52.7l27.2-101.4c2.7 9.02 8.2 16.1 16.6 21.22 8.4 5.1 18.77 7.63 31.1 7.63 15.3 0 29.9-3.7 43.75-11.1 13.9-7.42 25.9-18.1 36.1-31.9 10.2-13.8 17.77-29.8 22.6-47.9 4.9-18.13 5.9-34.3 3.1-48.45-2.85-14.17-9.16-25.14-18.9-32.9m174.65 80.65c-4.5 16.7-11.4 29.5-20.7 38.3-9.3 8.86-20.5 13.27-33.5 13.27-13.3 0-22.3-4.3-27-13-4.8-8.7-4.9-21.3-.5-37.8 4.4-16.5 11.42-29.4 21.12-38.7 9.7-9.3 21.05-13.94 34.07-13.94 13 0 21.8 4.5 26.4 13.4 4.6 8.93 4.63 21.76.15 38.5zm23.5-87.85l-6.73 25.1c-2.9-9.05-8.5-16.25-16.8-21.6-8.4-5.34-18.7-8-31-8-15.1 0-29.68 3.9-43.6 11.7-13.9 7.8-26.1 18.74-36.5 32.9-10.4 14.16-18 30.3-22.9 48.4-4.85 18.17-5.8 34.1-2.9 47.96 2.93 13.8 9.24 24.46 19 31.9 9.74 7.4 22.3 11.14 37.6 11.14 12.3 0 24.05-2.56 35.2-7.7a82.3 82.3 0 0 0 28.33-21.23l-7 26.18h51.9l47.38-176.7h-51.9zm269.87.06l.03-.05h-31.9c-1.02 0-1.92.05-2.85.07h-16.55l-8.5 11.8-2.1 2.8-.9 1.4-67.25 93.68-13.9-109.7h-55.08l27.9 166.7-61.6 85.3h54.9l14.9-21.13c.42-.62.8-1.14 1.3-1.8l17.4-24.7.5-.7 77.93-110.5 65.7-93 .1-.06h-.03z"></path></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="razor-wrapper-optns">
      <li>
        <div class="pay">
          <a href="#"></a>Payments
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><input type="submit" value="Bankings+" class="bank"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="line">
          <a href="#"></a>Line of Credit</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="line">
          <a href="#"></a>Payroll</div>
      </li>
      <li><input type="submit" value="Resources" class="bank"></li>
      <li><input type="submit" value="Support" class="bank"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="line">
          <a href="#"></a>Pricing</div>
      </li>
      <div class="end-wrap">
        <div class="flag">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="20" viewBox="0 0 28 20"><defs><filter id="a" width="129.2%" height="143.8%" x="-14.6%" y="-15.6%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="1"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.12 0"/><feMerge><feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"/><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge></filter></defs><g fill="none" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(2 1)"><path fill="#FAB446" d="M23.95 5.34H0V.44C0 .2.18 0 .41 0h23.13c.23 0 .41.2.41.42v4.9z"/><path fill="#73AF00" d="M23.54 15.99H.41a.42.42 0 0 1-.41-.42v-4.9h23.95v4.9c0 .23-.18.42-.41.42z"/><path fill="#F5F5F5" d="M0 5.34h23.95v5.32H0z"/><g fill="#41479B" transform="translate(9.73 5.71)"><path d="M2.25 4.55A2.24 2.24 0 0 1 .03 2.29c0-1.25 1-2.26 2.22-2.26a2.24 2.24 0 0 1 2.22 2.26c0 1.24-1 2.26-2.22 2.26zm0-4.1c-1 0-1.81.82-1.81 1.84a1.81 1.81 0 1 0 3.62.01c0-1.02-.8-1.84-1.8-1.84z"/><ellipse cx="2.25" cy="2.29" rx="1" ry="1"/><path d="M2.22 2.31l-.5-.41L.8.86.85.81l1.02.94.4.5zm0 0l.4.51 1.02.94.06-.05-.93-1.04-.5-.41z"/><path d="M2.22 2.26l.4-.5L3.65.8l.06.05-.93 1.04-.5.41zm0 0l-.5.41L.8 3.71l.05.05 1.02-.94.4-.5z"/><path d="M2.26 2.32l-.57.31-1.29.48-.03-.08 1.25-.6.61-.18z"/><path d="M2.26 2.32l.62-.19 1.24-.6-.03-.06-1.3.47-.56.31z"/><path d="M2.21 2.3l-.3-.58L1.44.41l.07-.03.59 1.26.18.63z"/><path d="M2.21 2.3l.19.63.58 1.26.07-.03-.47-1.31-.3-.58z"/><path d="M2.23 2.32l-.61-.19-1.25-.6.03-.06 1.3.47.56.31z"/><path d="M2.23 2.32l.57.31 1.3.48.02-.08-1.24-.6-.62-.18z"/><path d="M2.21 2.27l.19-.63.58-1.26.07.03-.47 1.31-.3.58zm0 0l-.3.58-.47 1.31.07.03.59-1.26.18-.63z"/></g><ellipse cx="11.98" cy="8" fill="#F5F5F5" rx="1" ry="1"/></g></svg>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-wrapper">
        <button type="submit" class="sign-wrapper">Sign Up <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- ---------------------hero section----------------------- -->
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <p id="first-head">
        Power your finance,
        <br> grow your business
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make a clone of Razorpay, expecting no horizontal space between the cta banner and hero sections. I don't want any white space between the cta banner and hero sections.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#first-head` section is inhering from `p` CSS including the margins, you should add this in your CSS:

```
#first-head {
   // ... other rules
   margin: 0 0 0 70px;
}
```

I would say this `p` element is useless or not optimal for SEO or accessibility. But it's my opinion.